# UITableView Scroll performing animation high CPU Usage

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I have a `UITableView` that is performing an animation on scroll, basically a sticky header, but instead it adjusts the height constraint of a `UIView`. I am getting really high CPU usage on scroll. Is there a better way to perform this animation?

Edit: I am not doing anything in the cellForRow at, function that would be causing this. It is definitely the scrollViewDidScroll function.

[image: CPU usage]

DidScroll:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

   let offset = scrollView.contentOffset.y + tableViewContentInsets
        if (lastPoint != nil) {

            if (lastPoint! < offset) {

                if (portfolioSummaryInitialHeight - offset < portfolioSummaryInitialHeight){
                    if (portfolioSummaryInitialHeight - offset > 0 ){
                        portfolioSummaryHeightConstraint.constant = portfolioSummaryInitialHeight - offset
                    } else {
                        portfolioSummaryHeightConstraint.constant = 0
                    }
                }

            } else {
                if (portfolioSummaryInitialHeight - offset < portfolioSummaryInitialHeight){
                    if (portfolioSummaryInitialHeight - offset > 0 ){
                        portfolioSummaryHeightConstraint.constant = portfolioSummaryInitialHeight - offset
                    }
                } else {
                    portfolioSummaryHeightConstraint.constant = portfolioSummaryInitialHeight
                }
            }
        }

        lastPoint = offset
   }
```

Additional Variables:

```
var tableViewContentInsets: CGFloat = 80
var portfolioSummaryInitialHeight: CGFloat = 0 // equals portfolioSummaryInitialHeight at viewDidLoad
var lastPoint: CGFloat?
```

[image: Dashboard]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your WillLayoutSubViews and DidLayoutSubViews functions. If you are doing lots of work in those functions then you need to add something like this:

```
var isScrolling: Bool = false

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

    if (isScrolling) {
        return
    } else {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    }
}
```

While your tableView is scrolling set `isScrolling = true` in `scrollViewDidEndDragging` set `isScrolling = false` this will ensure that your class will not do excessive work while the tableView is scrolling but insure that it will do the work in other instances. Might not be the best way to do this but it certainly works.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, I'd advise you to check if you perform any other heavy operations on the main thread e.g data fetch or something similar. I've created a simple test project with a plain table view and a header. Here is the code which does the resizes header. According to the CPU report, it utilizes 8% of CPU in high peaks.

[image: CPU report]

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var headerHeightConstr: NSLayoutConstraint! //header's height constraint
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
private var headerHeight: CGFloat = 128.0 ////header's height constraint initial value

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
}
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 100
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseID") else {
        return UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "reuseID")
    }
    return cell
}
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0 {
        self.headerHeightConstr.constant += abs(scrollView.contentOffset.y)
    } else if scrollView.contentOffset.y > 0 && self.headerHeightConstr.constant >= headerHeight {
        self.headerHeightConstr.constant -= scrollView.contentOffset.y
        if self.headerHeightConstr.constant < headerHeight {
            self.headerHeightConstr.constant = headerHeight
        }
    }
}
}
```

This is kinda naive approach but it works, will try to answer your questions if needed.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I can confirm that the app isn't doing any heavy lifting in the cellForRow function, it is definitely the scrolling method. I removed UIScrollViewDelegate from my extension, which gets the CPU usage to around 60% but it is still way too high. Not sure what is going wrong. You say this is a naive approach, what would be the best option?

Comment: "Naive approach" relates to my code, it can be improved by adding animations to make it resizing smoother.